# Delegate method to change navigationItem.titleView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I am trying to change the `ListViewController`'s `navigationItem.titleView` based on the row selected in `CollectionViewController`. I am trying to do this using a delegate method but its not working. `didSelectRowAt` is being called, but then the `func changeTitleView` is never being called. I'm not sure what's wrong. When I use the `func changeTitleView` inside `CollectionViewController` and use it within its own class, it works, so I know the function is working. I'm just not entirely sure how to pass the `String` data chosen from `CollectionVC` to `ListVC`. I'm very new to the delegate method.

Global Variable:

`var selectedCollection: CollectionItem?`

CollectionViewController:

```
protocol HandleTitleView {
  func doesThisWork(answer: String)
}

class CollectionViewController: UITableViewController {

  var handleTitleViewDelegate: HandleTitleView? = nil

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = collections[indexPath.row]
    selectedCollection = selectedItem
    let title = selectedCollection?.collectionTitle

    handleTitleViewDelegate?.doesThisWork(answer: title!)
  }
}
```

ListViewController:

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set up the collectionViewDelegate
    let collectionViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController") as! CollectionViewController
    collectionViewController.titleView = titleLabel
    collectionViewController.handleTitleViewDelegate = self
}

extension ListViewController: HandleTitleView {

  func doesThisWork(answer: String) {
    print(answer)

  }

}
```

I appreciate any help you can provide me. Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***

I am instantiating the `CollectionViewController` through a side menu named `MenuTableViewController`. I realized now that I need to chain delegate methods, however, `CollectionViewController` is embedded in a navigation bar so when I instantiate it, I have to instantiate `CollectionViewControllerNav` and am unable to set `MenuTableViewController` as the `CollectionVC` delegate:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row {

    case 0:

            let collectionViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController") as! CollectionViewController
            collectionViewController.handleTitleViewDelegate = self

            let collectionViewControllerNav = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewControllerNav")
            self.present(collectionViewControllerNav!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm not sure how to set the delegate method when this is the case

***UPDATE***

The delegate method works when I present the `CollectionViewController` but not its `CollectionViewControllerNav` counterpart

Comment: You can not override method in extension. For your problem you can use delegates methods by implementing did select method in collectionviewcontroller and delegate them to Listviewcontroller. In list view controller you conform with delegate and write your code.

Comment: Thank you for that piece of knowledge. I've updated the code (and my question) to reflect this change, however the delegate method/protocol function is still not being called. What else can I do to connect the two?

Comment: Can you able to  share some implementation. so i can look into it Thanks

Comment: I've updated my question. Please take a look, thanks

Comment: Kindly download the code from this link Thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_3YsdHYDEGZE1qQXQ3SkVWdlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely helpful. Can you take a look at my new question after implementing your advice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656677/method-being-called-but-not-executing-properly

Comment: Ok sure kindly vote up this answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

Extensions can not/should not override.

It is not possible to override functionality (like properties or methods) in extensions as documented in Apple's Swift Guide.

```
Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.
Apple Developer Guide
```

The compiler is allowing you to override in the extension for compatibility with Objective-C. But it's actually violating the language directive.

Instead of extennd CollectionViewcontroller for didSelectrow . you should implemnt didSelectRow method is CollectionViewController

Comment: Thank you for that piece of knowledge. I've updated the code (and my question) to reflect this change, however the delegate method/protocol function is still not being called. What else can I do to connect the two?

Comment: protocol HandleTitleView {
  func doesThisWork(answer: String) 
}

Comment: The protocol has been added. I put a breakpoint at `func doesThisWork(answer: String)` but the breakpoint never hits.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please take a look, thanks