# Method being called, but not executing properly

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uinavigationitem, swrevealviewcontroller

I have successfully chain linked delegate methods from `CollectionViewController` -> `MenuTableViewController` -> `ListViewController`. In `ListViewController` extension I call `changeTitleView()` but it is not working. The data, however is successfully passed because `print(title)` correctly prints passed information. `changeTitle()` executes properly if called from within `ListViewController`

```
class ListViewController { 
  var navigationTitle: String?

  @objc func changeTitle(title: String) {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
      let attributes: NSDictionary = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.1137, green: 0.1137, blue: 0.149, alpha: 0.8) /* #1d1d26 */,
        NSAttributedStringKey.kern:CGFloat(2.0)
      ]

      let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: 
      title.uppercased(), attributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject])
      titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle
      titleLabel.sizeToFit()
      self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
   }
}

extension ListViewController: HandleTitleView {
  @objc func changeTitleView(title: String) {
    print(title)
    self.navigationTitle = title

    changeTitle(title: navigationTitle!)
}
```

Additional information:

1) I am passing information through SWRevealController so not all data is within the same navigation stack. `ListViewController` is on top of `MenuTableViewController` and `CollectionViewController` is instantiated from `MenuTableViewController` and then dismissed

2) I created a button in `ListViewController` that calls `changeTitle()` and it successfully changes the `navigationItem.titleView` so I know the method works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried passing title instead of navigationTitle! ?

Comment: yes, unfortunately that didn't work so I tried passing it to a local variable (navigationTitle)

Comment: There's at least 2 syntax errors here, and the rest of the program is absent.  Are you sure the problem is here?

Comment: What are the syntax errors? and I can update the rest of the program if necessary. I believe the problem is here because if I add a print statement to the `HandleTitleView` protocol, that properly prints the `String` data passed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like below

```
class ListViewController { 
      var navigationTitle: String? {
           didSet{
              if(navigationTitle != nil) {
                  changeTitle(title: navigationTitle!)
              }
           }
      }
      @objc func changeTitle(title: String) { 
         let titleLabel = UILabel() 
         let attributes: NSDictionary = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.1137, green: 0.1137, blue: 0.149, alpha: 0.8) /* #1d1d26 */, NSAttributedStringKey.kern:CGFloat(2.0) ] 
         let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title.uppercased(), attributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject]) 
         titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle titleLabel.sizeToFit() 
         self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel 
    } 
} 
extension ListViewController: HandleTitleView { 
  @objc func changeTitleView(title: String) { 
    print(title) 
    self.navigationTitle = title
    // changeTitle(title: navigationTitle!) 
}`
```

Comment: Just tried it. Again, the method is called, but the titleView does not change. I'm thinking this has something to do with the fact that it's in an SWRevealController

Answer (score 0):

```
  @objc func changeTitle(title: String) {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let attributeFontSaySomething : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName :UIColor(red: 0.1137, green: 0.1137, blue: 0.149, alpha: 0.8),NSKernAttributeName : CGFloat(2.0) ]

    var attributes = attributeFontSaySomething

    let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: title.uppercased(), attributes: attributes)

    titleLabel.attributedText = attStringSaySomething
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

and you can download the code from this link

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_3YsdHYDEGUkh5OTI1a0FUZlU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it didn't work :( I think im just going to get rid of swrevealcontroller. It hasn't been updated since ios6 anyways